# trying to subtract a vector from a time series in the correct order

Tags: r

I have a time series  from 1951 to 2012. Part below

```
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
1951                                     15.50 18.74 22.75 25.90 25.43 27.61
1952 27.60 27.72 27.63 24.38 20.34 17.74 17.90 20.57 23.13 25.60 26.41 26.98
1953 25.80 26.19 24.99 23.23 19.59 15.78 14.85 18.97 20.44 25.78 26.65 27.00
1954 26.25 26.97 25.33 23.16 20.47 15.47 15.64 18.33 22.71 26.71 25.77 25.94
```

I also got vector of the means of all the Jans, Feb, etc, below

```
 [1] 27.80410 27.24500 26.14211 23.76737 20.19474 16.87368 16.71846 19.28359 22.74385
[10] 25.22513 26.50128 27.21410
```

I need to subtract the mean of January from all the Januaries, the same for February
 etc.

But if I do a simple subtract I will get January subtracting from Julys etc

The time series is a time series and the mean is a vector.

Can you tell me how to get past this and the whole process is part of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the `cycle` function to index the time series

```
ts1-v1[cycle(ts1)]
#       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
#1951                                     -1.21 -0.54  0.01  0.67 -1.07  0.41
#1952 -0.20  0.48  1.49  0.62  0.15  0.87  1.19  1.29  0.39  0.37 -0.09 -0.22
#1953 -2.00 -1.05 -1.15 -0.53 -0.60 -1.09 -1.86 -0.31 -2.30  0.55  0.15 -0.20
#1954 -1.55 -0.27 -0.81 -0.60  0.28 -1.40 -1.07 -0.95 -0.03  1.48 -0.73 -1.26
```

#### data

```
ts1 <- structure(c(15.5, 18.74, 22.75, 25.9, 25.43, 27.61, 27.6, 27.72, 
27.63, 24.38, 20.34, 17.74, 17.9, 20.57, 23.13, 25.6, 26.41, 
26.98, 25.8, 26.19, 24.99, 23.23, 19.59, 15.78, 14.85, 18.97, 
20.44, 25.78, 26.65, 27, 26.25, 26.97, 25.33, 23.16, 20.47, 15.47, 
15.64, 18.33, 22.71, 26.71, 25.77, 25.94), .Tsp = c(1951.5, 1954.91666666667, 
 12), class = "ts")


v1 <- c(27.80, 27.24, 26.14, 23.76, 20.19, 16.87, 16.71, 19.28, 22.74, 25.23,
 26.5, 27.2)
```

Comment: Thank you Tensibai